# How much later can GRE scores come in after a Jan. 15 masters application deadline?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, masters, gre

I am taking the GRE next week, but the universities I am applying to have their deadlines coming up Jan 15th (I graduated early so that's why I wasn't prepared with having already taken the GRE). I am wondering how long it will take before they start examining the applications fully and will no longer wait? My score will into the university 20 days after jan 15 so around feb. 5. Is this too late? I called one of these universities and they said it is o.k.

Comment: This can depend on the university. Some are more lax than others when it comes to GRE scores (one university I've talked to said they would be okay with late GRE scores because the time of arrival of scores is ETS's responsibility and not mine). But because of how this will vary depending on university, there's no one single answer that will be the correct answer for all universities. I would recommend contacting each university directly.

Comment: @ssjjaca You should repost as an answer. Also of note is that some adcoms will hold the entire application from evaluation until it is complete, which may impact chances of interviews.